# Bitcoind fails to start on Centos 5.8

Tags: bitcoind

When I try to start bitcoind on Centos 5.8 I immediately receive the following error:

```
bitcoind: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by bitcoind)
bitcoind: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by bitcoind)
bitcoind: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by bitcoind)
```

This is the version of glibc I have:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6|grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
```

About my operating system:

- OS: CentOS release 5.8 (Final) i686
- Glibc version: glibc-2.5-123
- libstdc++ version: libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5

Comment: Download the correct version or recompile for your platform.

Answer (score 5):

You can't run Bitcoin on CentOS 5. It's too old.

- You can't run the binaries because they are compiled against much newer versions of glibc and other critical libraries.
- You can't compile the source code because it requires much newer versions of libraries than are present in CentOS 5.

I ran into these issues when putting together [my Bitcoin yum repository for RHEL/Fedora](https://www.cryptorpms.com/). As you'll note, only EL 6 and 7 (and of course Fedora) are viable targets.

That's not to say that it's impossible; it's merely very difficult and a whole lot of work. And you shouldn't use old operating systems for new projects anyway.